# Is there a way to hide the fact that the object is cell fractured?

Tags: rigidbody, cell-fracture

As always I need to destroy something, but after I apply cell fracture to the objects, it is visible during close ups that it is consisted of individual pieces, is there a way to hide it?

Comment: the very cheap way is making the cells invisible and the original visible until hit time, then keyframe it vice versa

Comment: I thought about it but was looking for more professianal way, there must be something different

Comment: well - if you believe or not - professionals do often (!) hide things and make them visible by keyframes again. So if this is professional or not - if just your personal opinion.

Comment: ok thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WshXRndeOM -> i think he IS a professional ;)

Comment: guess elegant would be the right word, but yes, it works, thanks again!